# Re-enabling a cancelled account

Tags: azure, http-status-code-301, azure-web-app-service

I cancelled my "Pay-as-you-go" account that used to host my windows azure website.  today I looked on google however, and it decided to index the azure site (builtagroup.azurewebsites.net).  I want to re-enable my account and put a permanent redirect on the site until google removes it, but it's not letting me.  When I try to re-enable it, it just makes me create a new account, but does not let me have access to my old site.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Submit a support ticket. I don't believe there's an automated way to do this but if you can prove you are who you were before, then they might be able to fix this for you whether it means recovering things or simply blowing away the potentially-recoverable stuff just to allow you to re-create the same subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any current provision to re-enable cancelled account. You might have to open Billing Support ticket with Windows Azure Team and which is free.

> Support for billing and subscription management issues are covered
>   with your Windows Azure subscription at no additional charge, and you
>   don’t need to have a Windows Azure Support plan to raise these issues.
>   To submit an incident, go to the Windows Azure Support site and click
>   on Get Support

.